# Active Record Query to order by with multiple requirements

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a data set that has 3 columns (In this scenario)

`Product`, `start_date`, and `end_date`.

I currently am using

`@project.tasks.order(:product, :task_start_date).pluck(:product, :task_start_date, :task_end_date)`

Which returns them grouped up by product, and shows the 'grouped' ones by 'soonest starting' to 'latest starting'.

However, I would like the products to ALSO be sorted in that order.

AKA currently Product 1 is my enum:0 so it's first. However, it doesn't have a task due for 6 months.

Product 6 (enum:5) has a product due in a week, but is being shown as the 5th response.

Is it possible to switch this within a query, or would I need to modify my model?

EXAMPLE:

```
Product 4A, 08/23/2017, 08/24/2017
Product 1A, 12/21/2017, 08/20/2018
Product 4B, 01/10/2018, 08/10/2018
Product 1B, 02/20/2017, 08/10/2018
```

My current output would be

```
1A
1B
4A
4B
```

I would like it to be

```
4A
4B
1B // Each -product- should be ordered by start_date also
1A
```

Comment: Not quite clear to me what you mean with task. How do the Products relate to the tasks?

Comment: @tschoppi Product is a non-model column within Task. A 'task' will have the product in which the task is for associated. It is an enumarable under Task.

This 'task' is to improve the response time of the Messenger (product) App. It will belong to a Project.